# Android приложение и взаимодействие с сервером

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sqlite, contentprovider

Пишу мобильное приложение-клиент, все действия делает сервер, моему приложению необходимо просто посылать запросы на сервер и оттуда получать информацию.
В целом, функциональность должна быть схожа с приложением olx (продажи).
Есть метод api, который возвращает мне N объявлений.
Как мне на постоянной основе взаимодействовать с сервером и как-нибудь сохранять информацию, чтобы лишний раз не посылать запросы? На данный момент использую IntentService для получения данных + sqlite для хранения промежуточных данных, чтобы UI обновлять из нее + ContentProvider.
Кто-нибудь может посоветовать другое решение или я нахожусь на правильном пути?